# Find a specific file, or find all executable files within the system path

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-system

I wrote a function to find a specific file, or all the executable files with a given `name` and accessing `flag`, and I want to make sure it is as cross-platform as possible. Currently, I'm using the PATHEXT environment variable to get the extensions for files that the operating system considers executable.

```
import os

class CytherError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        Exception.__init__(self, message)
        self.message = 'CytherError: {}'.format(repr(message))

def where(name, flags=os.F_OK):
    result = []
    extensions = os.environ.get('PATHEXT', '').split(os.pathsep)
    if not extensions:
        raise CytherError("The 'PATHEXT' environment variable doesn't exist")

    paths = os.environ.get('PATH', '').split(os.pathsep)
    if not paths:
        raise CytherError("The 'PATH' environment variable doesn't exist")

    for path in paths:
        path = os.path.join(path, name)
        if os.access(path, flags):
            result.append(os.path.normpath(path))
        for ext in extensions:
            whole = path + ext
            if os.access(whole, flags):
                result.append(os.path.normpath(whole))
    return result
```

**Usage:**

```
In[-]: where('python')

Out[-]: "C:\Python35\python.exe"
```

Please be brutal in pointing out anything you find, except for:

1. Commenting
2. Docstrings
3. PEP 8 spacing

I will have these things covered later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could have just used the function `which()`, offered by `shutil`. [Documented here](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/shutil.html#shutil.which).

Example:

```
>>> from shutil import which
>>> which('python')
'C:\Python35\python.exe'
```

Comment: In my setup (Cygwin), `shutil.which` doesn't return anything for files the system doesn't consider executable, e.g. `.py` scripts. This function you've written does; I have uses for the function as you've written it.

Answer (score 2):

- I don't know why you even use extensions.  If it isn't executable according to `os`, why bother checking the extensions?
- You search only the directories that are directly in `$PATH`, but not the sub-directories.
- You can use `os.defpath` to find the executable paths on the system instead of relying on environment variables.
- Your code always returns copies.  For example, `where('python')` on my computer returns `['/usr/bin/python', '/usr/bin/python']`.  I believe that is because you didn't `continue` in `if os.access(whole, flags):`.  Since you didn't `continue`, that would mean that one file could match for both executability and its file extension.

My modified version of your code is as follows:

```
def where(name, flags=os.F_OK):
    result = []
    paths = os.defpath.split(os.pathsep)
    for outerpath in paths:
        for innerpath, _, _ in os.walk(outerpath):
            path = os.path.join(innerpath, name)
            if os.access(path, flags):
                result.append(os.path.normpath(path))
    return result
```

As for your exception class, you really don't need the `__init__` method at all.  The `Exception` class will take care of the message.  In fact, modifying `self.message` does not effect how the exception is displayed.  You whole class could look like this:

```
class CytherError(Exception):
    pass
```

Comment: According to this issue: https://bugs.python.org/issue5717, os.defpath does not work on windows. I also don't need to search the subdirectories. I did take your suggestion on changing CytherError and adding the continue.

Comment: Also, in windows, `os.X_OK` will return if the file is *openable*, not executable. For example, `os.access('D:/Python35/README.txt', os.X_OK)` will return `True`.Your following code returns an empty list to me.

Comment: Nick, I don't see any `continue` statement in your edit. Where should the `continue` statement be inserted?

Comment: Why not use, on windows, 'os.environ["PATH"]' instead?